# iphone: Is there any changes needed for the production of app having inapp purchase?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, inappsettings

I have implemented inApp purchase with dummy user and test bundle identifier. and its working fine

Now it is going to be upload.so what changes are needed to work inApp on live app, other than bundle identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary you submit to Apple should be exactly the same one you did your testing with! There is no need to change anything, including the bundle ID. You make your In App Purchase live by submitting it for review by Apple, much in the same way you do for a new app. (Except you include a screen-shot instead of a new app binary.)

You access the sandbox by logging in as one of the test users that you created in iTunes Connect.